# How to automatically start tmux when opening gnome-terminal

Tags: gnome, 18.04, launcher, gnome-terminal

I want the terminal to always start `tmux` (a "terminal multiplexer") automatically in every new terminal I open. I tried modifying `org.gnome.Terminal.desktop` and `gnome-terminal.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applications`. In these files, I changed the lines

```
Exec=gnome-terminal
```

to

```
Exec=gnome-terminal -- tmux
```

Similarly for the `TryExec` lines. However, this did not make tmux start automatically in every new terminal I open. I tried logging out and in again, and I also tried to modify the system-wide settings in `/usr/share/applications`. None of this worked. Any idea of what I am missing?

Comment: @damadam I am not sure I understand: I don't care about firefox, I want gnome-terminal. I really don't get what you mean.

Comment: can you explain with a little more detail your question (by editing it)? because I had understand that you want to change the command launched by terminal icon/ **Ctrl** + **Alt** + **T**

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to change your `gnome-terminal` default profile to run `tmux` as a custom command in place of your shell? see [Custom commands and shells](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/pref-custom-command.html.en)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Method involving a change to `.bashrc`**

The most simple approach probably involves adding the `tmux` command to your `.bashrc`, so it automatically gets executed whatever way you start the terminal. As suggested in [the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux#Start_tmux_on_every_shell_login), one can add the following lines of code in `.bashrc`:

```
# If not running interactively, do not do anything
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return
# Otherwise start tmux
[[ -z "$TMUX" ]] && exec tmux
```

**Method that involves changing launchers and hotkey**

This method involves changing the launchers (`.desktop` files) for the terminal. This will not affect the hotkeys because these directly refer to the executables, so also the way hotkeys are setup needs to be changed.

- In the `.desktop` file, specify "tmux" on the `Exec=` line. Add (or edit) a line to say `Terminal=true`.
- For changing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> key combination, go to Settings - Keyboard. Disable the existing hotkey for Launch Terminal (click the line "Launch Terminal", then when the dialog appears, hit backspace, then click "Set"). Now create your custom hotkey. At the bottom of the list, hit +. Provide a name (e.g. "Launch terminal") and the command: `gnome-terminal -- tmux`. Finally, set the hotkey. Alternatively, you could install the utility `dex`, available in Universe. Then the hotkey can be set up to launch the modified `.desktop` file with a command `dex .

Comment: Yes, but gnome-terminal accepts further commands after `--` to be executed after a gnome-terminal is started. This is equivalent to the deprecated `-e` option. See `man gnome-terminal`.

Comment: I see, tmux is not an alternative terminal emulator, but runs in a terminal, similar to GNU screen. I will look into it for the .desktop file, but for Ctrl+Alt+t, just substitute the command "gnome-terminal -- tmux".

Comment: For the .desktop, it will work adding a line "Terminal=true". That runs the command you specify, tmux, in the standard terminal emulator. Updated my answer.

Comment: If I add Terminal=true, the launcher disappears from everywhere. But the keybinding works, which is already more than half of a solution.

Comment: I added a better solution, which is to add the command to your .bashrc. Anyway, the launcher approach works for me: make sure you modified yours correctly.

Comment: The .bashrc solution is very neat, silly I did not think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/21115906/12771561, I found the simplest solution ever:

1. You need this command `gnome-terminal -e tmux`. In my case, I use qterminal, so for me, the command is `qterminal -e tmux`.
2. In the shortcuts menu, I replaced the command for `Ctrl+T` with `qterminal -e tmux`.
   And that's it!